# HTTParty cannot get id of album

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, httparty

I'm building a rails app and I'm trying to grab some data from an API.

This is my controller

```rb
require 'will_paginate/array'

class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @albums = HTTParty
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums', :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
      .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

and this is my index view

```rb
<main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-5">Albums</h1>
    <p class="lead">Here we show all albums and it's details</p>

    <div class="row">
      <% @albums.each do |album| %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h5 class="card-title">
            <%= album['title'] %>
          </h5>

          <p>User_id: <%= album['user_id'] %> | id: <%= album['id'] %><p>
          <%= link_to "View Album", album, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= will_paginate @albums, renderer: WillPaginate::ActionView::BootstrapLinkRenderer, class: 'margin-auto' %>
</main>
```

The issue here is the link, I have `resources :albums` in the routes file.

```
                               albums GET    /albums(.:format)                                                                        albums#index
                                      POST   /albums(.:format)                                                                        albums#create
                            new_album GET    /albums/new(.:format)                                                                    albums#new
                           edit_album GET    /albums/:id/edit(.:format)                                                               albums#edit
                                album GET    /albums/:id(.:format)                                                                    albums#show
                                      PATCH  /albums/:id(.:format)                                                                    albums#update
                                      PUT    /albums/:id(.:format)                                                                    albums#update
                                      DELETE /albums/:id(.:format)                                                                    albums#destroy
                           users_show GET    /users/show(.:format)                                                                    users#show
                                 root GET    /                                                                                        albums#index
```

However, when I hover over the button it is linking to the following

[image]

How do I go about only linking to the ID i.e. localhost:3000/albums/2

UPDATE 1

routes.rb

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :albums
  get 'users/show'

  root 'albums#index'
end
```

Comment: It's not necessary or desirable that you put in tags or headers such as "UPDATE 1". SO has a revision tracking system so we can see if something has changed. Instead, simply incorporate any updates or changes into the question's text as if you'd had it there originally. It helps maintain the readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be easy.

This is how you get the album id:

```
album['id']
```

And you can use the ID to get the link:

```
<%= link_to "View Album", album_path(album['id']), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

### Warning: Path must be singular! album_path

```
# add to your routes.rb
resources :albums
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm really really rusty with rails haha so getting back into it. I tried your solution, I'm getting `/albums.1` not getting a slash but a dot

Comment: @B.J.B try the above routes helper - i have edited the answer

Comment: actually you'll have to paste in your existing routes. or you can just write `resources :albums` in your `routes.rb` file it may create some extra routes, but that should work.

Comment: I'm still getting a dot unfortunately

Comment: oops i made a mistake. Use `album_path` SINGULAR. i'll update the answer

Comment: Ohh gotcha. Thanks :)